# Update Component State (And UI) With Random Word From Array At Set Interval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I'd like to update a word in a React component every second with a random value from an array. The state seems to update at the interval just fine in DevTools, but there is a weird bug in the browser that I can't seem to pinpoint: 
 the text flashes, almost as if it's "scrolling" through the old strings to the new one. Any advice on how to smooth this out would be much appreciated!

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    name: ""
  }
  getWord = () => {
    let randomWords = ["Friend", "Enemy", "Santa"];
    const randomWord = randomWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomWords.length)];

    this.setState({
      name: randomWord
    });
  }

  render() {
    setInterval(this.getWord, 1000);
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the `getWord` to do what the name implies: To get a word, return a `string`.. Not to set the state. To set a state in a function called `getWord` is misleading and would be considered a side-effect. You'll understand what I mean when you get more experienced :)

Then you should use `componentDidMount` to set up the timer. Something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    var _this = this;
    setInterval(function() {
        var newName = _this.getWord();
        _this .setState({name: newName });
    }, 1000);
}
```

This is what react is about... You set new props or the state (either using `state`, or `Redux` or whatever) and let React to re-render.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `setInterval` in `render()`. Every second you get another ine, so by the tenth flash, it's rerendering 10 times, hence the flicker. Render methods should have no side effects, as this is adding another interval every time it renders. Try it in `componentDidMount`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: ""
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    setInterval(this.getWord, 1000);
  }

  getWord = () => {
    let randomWords = ["Friend", "Enemy", "Santa"];
    const randomWord = randomWords[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomWords.length)];

    console.log('new word', randomWord)
    this.setState({
      name: randomWord
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App
```